# Why do I can't use more than one Java increment or decrement operators?

Tags: java, operators

*I am so suprise when I using two Java increment operators at the same time.*
Please check below codes..

```
public class Testing {

public static void main(String... str) {
    int prefix = 0, postfix = 0, both = 0;
    // Testing prefix
    System.out.println(prefix);
    System.out.println(++prefix);
    System.out.println(prefix);
    // Testing postfix
    System.out.println(postfix);
    System.out.println(postfix++);
    System.out.println(postfix);
    // mixing both prefix and postfix (I think this should be fine)
    // System.out.println(++ both ++);
  }
}
```

Why I can't use as `++ both ++` ? Could anyone explain me please ? Thanks..

Comment: `Why I can't use as ++ both ++`  , can you explain  ?  How you want to use them?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I imagined that *first-increase in first time execution ,and then later increase again*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of `++x` or `x++` is categorized as a *value*, not a *variable* - and both operators will only work on variables.

For example, from [section 15.14.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2):

> A postfix expression followed by a ++ operator is a postfix increment expression.
>
> ```
>     PostIncrementExpression:
>        PostfixExpression ++
> ```
>
> The result of the postfix expression must be a variable of a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> The type of the postfix increment expression is the type of the variable. The result of the postfix increment expression is not a variable, but a value.

(Pretty much identical language is used for the `PrefixIncrementExpression` in 15.14.3.)

Answer (score 3):

For example

`int i = 0;`

now `i++` ==> 1

now `1++` is the error.  `++` is used only for variables not for constants.

Answer (score 1):

`++prefix` it will expand before the value printed in console. But 
`prefix++` will printed and then only expand. assigning the values, you will get the same result. But using Sout the result may differ on that print time only.

Comment: it's the last commented out line they are asking about

Answer (score 1):

These operators come from the C language, where every expression, operations included, has a value.

`++` is an operator, but it also defines a value:

`i++` *means* that after this instruction is executed, the variable `i` has received the value of `i+1`. The *value* of the expression `(i++)` is the value of `i`.

`++i` *means* that after this instruction is executed, the variable `i` has received the value of `i+1`. The *value* of the expression `(++i)` is the value of the expression `(i+1)`.

`++ i ++` has no meaning if you consider the above. `++ i ++` would be either `(++i)++` or `++(i++)` and both expressions are invalid since `++` is applied to variables and both `(i++)` and `(++i)` are values.

The same way, `i++ ++` has no meaning either because it would be `(i++)++` and `(i++)` is the value of `i`, not a variable.

The following page explains this in more detail: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx7b.html

If you will, let's write an equivalent to `i++`:

```
int var_pp(int * var) {
    temp = *var;
    *var = temp + 1;
    return temp;
}
```

`i++` and `var_pp(&i)` behave the same way.

Let's write an equivalent to `++i`:

```
int pp_var(int * var) {
    *var = *var + 1;
    return *var;
}
```

`++i` and `pp_var(&i)` behave the same way.

Other combinations of `++` operators have undefined behavior: consider `i++ + ++i`, what happens depends on how the compiler understands this code and when it performs the `store i` operation. Because combinations of those operators are highly ambiguous, they are undefined by the language. Your compiler might or might not warn you, and if it doesn't, the result will depend on its implementation.

Comment: Thanks for detail explanation , I really appreciated. but this statement *The value of the expression (++i) is the value of the expression (i+1).* I think `(++i)` is the value of expression `(i+=1)`.

Comment: That's exactly the same: `i+=1` means that after the instruction is exectued, the variable `i` has received the value of `i+1`. The value of the expression `(i+=1)` is the value of the expression `(i+1)`

Comment: No , `(i+=1)` and `(i+1)` aren't the same because `i` update it's value after execution `(i+=1)` while `(i+1)` not.

Comment: I'm not saying they are the same, they are different expressions that do different things, but they evaluate to the same value. `k=i+1` is another completely different operation, but the value of this expression `k=i+1` is yet again `i+1`

Comment: Thanks , now I really understand what you mean .. Thanks for your valuable times. :)